# Unable to add a key, value pair in active record in Rails 3.2.14, Ruby 2.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Recently I upgraded the ruby version used by my Rails app from 1.9 to 2.1.0.
Previously the below code used to work:

```
# in Ruby 1.9
user = User.first
# then adding my own field to it
user[:phone_no] = "+91 0000 888 773"

# but now in Ruby 2.1.0,
user[:phone_no] = "+91 0000 888 773"
```

The above piece of code is throwing this error.

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for :warn:Symbol
from /home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/deprecation/reporting.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in warn'
from /home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/deprecation/reporting.rb:13:in `each'
from /home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/deprecation/reporting.rb:13:in `block in warn'
from /home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/deprecation/reporting.rb:12:in `tap'
from /home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/deprecation/reporting.rb:12:in `warn'
from /home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:32:in `write_attribute'
from /home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:67:in `write_attribute'
from /home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:31:in `[]='
from (irb):3
from /home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

For fixing this now I am creating a new hash and then adding additional fields to it.

```
new_user = {}
new_user[:address] = user.address
new_user[:first_name] = user.first_name
new_user[:last_name] = user.last_name
```

I am unable to understand why the previous code is not working in Ruby 2.1.0.
I have been getting this issue after upgrading ruby at many places in different scenarios for e.g. while rendering template.

```
# in Ruby 1.9, this used to work and not in Ruby 2.0
render :template=>"share/index.html.erb"
# in Ruby 2.0, the below code works
render :template=>"share/index"
```

I do not know what has changed in Ruby 2.0 which is causing all these errors.

Comment: Can you post the full backtrace ?

Comment: That is the complete backtrace, in which ever line I try to add a key to a record fetched from DB, it throws this error: `undefined method \`call' for :warn:Symbol`. You can try it out in rails console.

Comment: how you are trying to access phone number ?

Comment: I just want to render the response in `json`, using this: `render :json => @user_list.as_json(:only=>[:address,:first_name, :last_name, :phone_no])`, but this was only working in ruby 1.9 . I do this so that I need not expose the entire parameter list to client side.

Comment: Please use @user_list = User.select(::address,:first_name, :last_name).
After that if you want to add more attribute you can use merge! function

Comment: I have changed it now, @user_list = User.select("address,first_name, last_name") as this works in rails 3, but still the main question is not answered, how can I add anyother field to this hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the user record as shown below:

@user_list = User.select("address,first_name, last_name")

After that you can merge any attributes by using merge! as shown below :

render :json => @user_list.as_json.map{|x|x.merge!("phone"=>"123456789")}